# Refactor foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

Is there a way to make this more efficient?

```
    //After trimming validate
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        //Check to see if any field is blank
        if ($key == 'ref_type') {
            if (!in_array($key, array('loan', 'member'))) {
                $errors['ref_type'] = 'Choose one of the presented options.';
            }
        } 
        if ($key == 'loan_ref') {
            if ($value == '') {
                $errors['loan_ref'] = 'This field must not be empty.';
            }
        }
        if ($key == 'member_ref') {
            if ($value == '') {
                $errors['member_ref'] = 'This field must not be empty.';
            }
        }
        if ($key == 'transaction_amount') {
            if ($value == '') {
                $errors['transaction_amount'] = 'This field must not be empty.';
            }
        }
        if ($key == 'custom_description') {
            if ($value == '') {
                $errors['custom_description'] = 'This field must not be empty.';
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe instead of the if's use is in_array?

Thanks

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh thanks, didn't know there was a code review exchange site :)

Comment: start by converting to switch

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the first if: You check whether `$key == 'ref_type'` and then again if `$key` is one of the array values. as `ref_type` is not in the array `in_array()` will always return -1. Shouldn't that be `!in_array($value, array('loan', 'member')`?

Comment: @Sirko Right. I think his code is supposed to be using `$value` instead of `$key` here: `in_array($value, array('loan', 'member')`

Comment: You're right sorry wrong var.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the best, but still better.

```
$expected = array('loan_ref', 'member_ref' /* etc. */);

//After trimming validate
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
//Check to see if any field is blank
    if ($key == 'ref_type') {
            if (!in_array($key, array('loan', 'member'))) {
                $errors['ref_type'] = 'Choose one of the presented options.';
            }
    }

    if (in_array($key, $expected) && empty($value)) {
             $errors[$key] = 'This field must not be empty.';
    }
}
```

Edited according to Jonathon Reinhart's comment.

Comment: Yup -- was going to suggest this method for checking the empty values. Less code duplication.

Comment: 1) This still has the same bug the OP's code has. 2) This means that *any* empty POST value will generate an error, even if it's not one the code should actually care about.   Explicit > Implicit when it comes to sanitization.

Answer (score 3):

#### All together:

```
//After trimming validate
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    //Check to see if any field is blank
    $not_empty_list = array("custom_description", "transaction_amount", "member_ref", "loan_ref");
    if ($value == '' && in_array($value,$not_empty_list)) {
        $errors[$value] = 'This field must not be empty.';
    }
    if ($key == 'ref_type' && !in_array($key, array('loan', 'member'))) {
            $errors['ref_type'] = 'Choose one of the presented options.';
    } 
}
```

This of course assuming that `$_POST` can have more indexes than just the ones in "custom_description", "transaction_amount", "member_ref", "loan_ref".

---

#### Step by step

This condition:

```
$list=array("custom_description", "transaction_amount", "member_ref", "loan_ref");
if ($value == '' && in_array($value,$list)) {
   $errors[$value] = 'This field must not be empty.';
}
```

Can replace this block:

```
    if ($key == 'loan_ref') {
        if ($value == '') {
            $errors['loan_ref'] = 'This field must not be empty.';
        }
    }
    if ($key == 'member_ref') {
        if ($value == '') {
            $errors['member_ref'] = 'This field must not be empty.';
        }
    }
    if ($key == 'transaction_amount') {
        if ($value == '') {
            $errors['transaction_amount'] = 'This field must not be empty.';
        }
    }
    if ($key == 'custom_description') {
        if ($value == '') {
            $errors['custom_description'] = 'This field must not be empty.';
        }
    }
```

Then in the other part you can join the two conditions. From:

```
    if ($key == 'ref_type') {
        if (!in_array($key, array('loan', 'member'))) {
            $errors['ref_type'] = 'Choose one of the presented options.';
        }
    }
```

to:

```
    if ($key == 'ref_type' && !in_array($key, array('loan', 'member'))) {
            $errors['ref_type'] = 'Choose one of the presented options.';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you could use if {} else if {} since the keys can only be equal to a single value.

You could also use a [Switch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

Comment: Might be nice to know that a switch and a elseif() are almost exactly as fast :)

Answer (score 1):

Why iterate at all?  Just access what you want directly:

```
if (isset($_POST['ref_type')) {
    if (!in_array($_POST['ref_type'], array('loan', 'member'))
        // Error, bad entry given
}
else {
    // Error, ref_type is missing
}
```

Note that your code *does not* check for required POST variables. If they don't exist, the foreach loop simply doesn't care.  This way, you're explicitly checking for required variables.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:
The first one is an execption, thats why I use that one as you do. Then, instead of checking if the key matches a string, I first check if it is empty. Only when it is empty im going to check more specific, and check by key.
**The whole in_array test is weird though. You check if the key matches something, and continue to to test if it's something else... You allready know its not.**

```
//After trimming validate
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    //Check to see if any field is blank
    if ($key == 'ref_type') {
        // The following test is weird, you allready know $key=='ref_type'
        if (!in_array($key, array('loan', 'member'))) {
            $errors['ref_type'] = 'Choose one of the presented options.';
        }
    } 
    else{
        if ($value == '') {
                if ($key == 'loan_ref') {          $errors['loan_ref'] = 'This field must not be empty.'; }
            elseif ($key == 'member_ref') {        $errors['member_ref'] = 'This field must not be empty.'; }
            elseif ($key == 'transaction_amount'){ $errors['transaction_amount'] = 'This field must not be empty.'; }
            elseif ($key == 'custom_description') {    $errors['custom_description'] = 'This field must not be empty.'; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkRef($key) {
   switch ($key) {
            case 'ref_type':
                if (!in_array($key, array('loan', 'member'))) {
                $output = 'Choose one of the presented options.';
            }
                break;
            case 2:
                //repeat for other status
                break;
            case 3:
                $output = "Silver";
                break;
            case 4:
                $output = "Bronze";
                break;
            default:
                $output = "ROWS EMPTY";
        }
    return $output;
}

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
   $errors[$key] = checkRef($key);
}
```

something like this using a function

Answer (score 1):

you can use switch/case : and group the similar cases :

```
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        //Check to see if any field is blank
        switch($key){
         case 'ref_type':
            if (!in_array($key, array('loan', 'member'))) {
                $errors['ref_type'] = 'Choose one of the presented options.';
            }
            break;
         case 'loan_ref':
         case 'member_ref':
         case 'transaction_amount':
         case 'custom_description':
            if ($value == '') {
                $errors[$key] = 'This field must not be empty.';
            }
            break;
        default:
            // no check for others fields ?
            break;
        }
     }
```

I personally would also replace the 4 similar cases by `default:`

Answer (score 1):

Processing of `ref_type` is different, so you can separate it out.  Then loop over the remaining fields and check them:

```
if(!isset($_POST['ref_type']) ||
   !in_array($_POST['ref_type'], array('loan', 'member')) {

    $errors['ref_type'] = 'Choose one of the presented options.';
}

$fields = array('loan_ref', 'member_ref', 'transaction_amount', 'custom_description');

foreach($fields as $key) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$key]) || $_POST[$key] == '') {
        $errors[$key] = "Field $key must not be empty.";
    }
}
```